# How does Google Keep fetch link preview?

Tags: facebook-opengraph, google-keep, link-prefetch

My websites (which are just recovered from an attack) are fetched like this in Google Keep. However testing with Facebook Open Graph Debugger they appear normal. So is there a way to know what mechanism GK uses to fetch link preview?

[image]

<sup>Also asked in [Google Help Center](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/39566716?hl=en&msgid=39566716)</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a sign of a cloaking hack. See [Fixing the Japanese keyword hack | Web Fundamentals](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/hacked/fixing_the_japanese_keyword_hack) for more